# Laravel Boilerplate and Bootstrap

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, core-ui

I have a question about Bootstrap and CoreUI on Laravel Boilerplate.

I've been trying to use some core features that are a part of Bootstrap by default, however, some things just don't work. Collapse, Modals, these features don't seem to be available. Is there something I'm missing? Some element that is customizable and needs to be loaded?

Any advice on where to look would be helpful as I'm having trouble even determining where to search for researching a solution.

Comment: for Collapse, Modals you need to include js. can you show us some code? Especially the `app.blade.php`

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean Andy. I'm running on Laravel Boilerplate, which uses CoreUI and has Bootstrap included by default. A lot of Bootstrap styling and features are there, but functions like Collapse and Modal don't seem to be working. I've looked at the Bootstrap documentation and I don't see any plugins required for that